# redirect in Spring MVC occur Infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `Spring 3.1.1` and `tomcat 5.5.31`

The invoke method in the cardproducer.jsp file:

```
window.location.href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteCardProducer/"
                + id + ".html";
```

The Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteCardProducer/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model,RedirectAttributes att,HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    if(service.deleteCardProducer(id)){
        return getCardProducerList(model,request);
    }else{
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", resource.getMessage(
                "error.relevantCardProducer", new Object[] {},
                LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
        return "redirect:cardProducer.html";
    }
}
```

After delete it should list all cardProducers:

```
@RequestMapping("/cardProducer")
public String getCardProducerList(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("cardProducerList", service.getAllProducer());
    try {
        if (request.getParameter("errorMessage")==null) {
            return "cardproducer/cardProducer";
        }

            String errorMessage=new String(request.getParameter("errorMessage").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "GBK");
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage",errorMessage);
            log.info("request.getParameter(errorMessage):"+errorMessage);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            log.error("errors"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return "cardproducer/cardProducer";
```

The log info show the request URL is cardpro as follow:

```
 2014-12-19 16:21:09,997 DEBUG 

web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:138) http-8080-2 - queryCardProducer relevant  sql String is ~select count(1) from ops_writecardlog t where t.supplier='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,012 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:136) http-8080-2 - deleteCardProducer sql String is ~delete ops_cardproducer where id='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,013 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:138) http-8080-2 - queryCardProducer relevant  sql String is ~select count(1) from ops_writecardlog t where t.supplier='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,027 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:136) http-8080-2 - deleteCardProducer sql String is ~delete ops_cardproducer where id='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,029 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:138) http-8080-2 - queryCardProducer relevant  sql String is ~select count(1) from ops_writecardlog t where t.supplier='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,043 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:136) http-8080-2 - deleteCardProducer sql String is ~delete ops_cardproducer where id='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,044 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:138) http-8080-2 - queryCardProducer relevant  sql String is ~select count(1) from ops_writecardlog t where t.supplier='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,057 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:136) http-8080-2 - deleteCardProducer sql String is ~delete ops_cardproducer where id='cardProducer'
 2014-12-19 16:21:10,059 DEBUG web.persistence.HBOPSWebDaoImpl.deleteCardProducer(HBOPSWebDaoImpl.java:138) http-8080-2 - queryCardProducer relevant  sql String is ~select count(1) from ops_writecardlog t where t.supplier='cardProducer'
```

The right things is delete cardProducer then show all of them. It causes an infinite loop.

Comment: Could you please post service.deleteCardProducer(id)) code?

Comment: @RRR The service code:
`@Override
 public boolean deleteCardProducer(String id) {
  return dao.deleteCardProducer(id);
 }`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar and the dao code:`@Override
 public boolean deleteCardProducer(String id) {
  String sql ="delete ops_cardproducer where id='"+id+"'"; 
  log.debug("deleteCardProducer sql String is ~" + sql);
  String sql2="select count(1) from ops_writecardlog t where t.supplier='"+id+"'";
  log.debug("queryCardProducer relevant  sql String is ~" + sql2);
  if (jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql2)!=0) {
   return false;
  }else{
   return jdbcTemplate.update(sql)>0;
  }
  
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your redirect is not going back to root. When you redirect via `"redirect:cardProducer.html"`, I am guessing that it is just appending this to your current URI, producing something like `"/deleteCardProducer/cardProducer.html"`. It is redirecting to this, which is picked up by the delete controller, and redirects again and again.

Instead, you need to redirect back to root. Something with a beginning slash like `"redirect:/cardProducer.html"`.

You should be able to open the console in your browser and see what the location header values are (the redirect URIs).

Comment: Thanks.The problem solved! and update sth in Controller file,`att.addAttribute("errorMessage", resource.getMessage(
                "error.relevantCardProducer", new Object[] {},
                LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));`

Answer (score 0):

> you can try -  modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/cardProducer");
>
> // In my project I have used **Tiles** for templating